# compare ip with range in two tables

Tags: sql-server, ip

I work actually on a SQL server, to make a code. I have two tables :

- first ==> ip of computers
- second ==> Range ip (min and max)

I have found some informations on Internet about that, but can't find how do it correctly.

For information, i have my join between two tables, my problem is to see if the `tableA.ip` is in the range from `TableB.rangemini` and `TableB.rangemax`.

I check too if the country from `tableA` is the same of `TableB`.

```
SELECT TableA.name
,TableA.[Country]
,TableA.[Adresse IP]
,TableB.[CountryB]
,TableB.[IP Range Min]
,TableB.[IP Range Max]

 FROM TableA
 RIGHT JOIN TableB
 ON TableA.[Country] = TableB.[CountryB]
```

I don't have an error message, i just don't know how do correctly a parse, to find if IP from `TableA` is in the range from `TableB`.

If anyone has an idea, and can help me, it will be very appreciated.

In advance, thank you for your help.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would really help here if you posted the table definitions (create table statements) and sample data (insert statements). Additionally some sample output would be really helpful. I just can't figure out exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: `CASE WHEN TableA.[Adresse IP] >= TableB.[IP Range Min] AND TableA.[Adresse IP] <= TableB.[IP Range Max] THEN 'In Range' ELSE 'Not In Range' END InRange`?

Comment: Hello and thank you Sami. Yes it's exactly that